# Shop page behaves different depending on the way I visit it (direct URI or from the home page menu)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-mobile

I am developing a theme with jQuery and I don't know why but my shop page displays different css depending on where I come from. I mean if I get there by the home page shop button [danielvivancos.com/edu/wordpress](http://danielvivancos.com/edu/wordpress) then it is styled one way but if I get there directly by [www.danielvivancos.com/edu/wordpress/shop/](http://www.danielvivancos.com/edu/wordpress/shop/) then the styles change (the form and the products list). You sure can see the difference.
Anyone knows how this is happening? or if this has something to do with jquery or wordpress core?

Comment: Looks the same to me on OS X/Chrome. What browser(s) does it look different in?

Comment: Nop, it doesn't display the same. I mean the content is the same but if you go to danielvivancos.com/edu/wordpress and then from there you click on shop menu item then you will see that the form is above the items list. But if you go directly to danielvivancos.com/edu/wordpress/shop yu will see that the form is "inside" of the first element in the list. By form I mean the words "Ordre predeterminat". Check it again and you will see it's different. I've tried this on Chrome and Mozilla. Any ideas?